# How to add a stamp to a pdf with python (PyPDF)

Tags: python, pypdf

I am trying to add a stamp to a pdf and have done so like this

```
import PyPDF2 as pypdf
    
workbook.save(excel_file)

reader = pypdf.PdfReader("/home/littlejiver/loadprocesser/images/PPB - DIFRTACC.pdf")
image_page = reader.pages[0]

writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()

reader = pypdf.PdfReader("/home/littlejiver/loadprocesser/Bills/Bison/INV-5163148A.PDF")
content_page = reader.pages[0]
mediabox = content_page.mediabox
content_page.merge_page(image_page)
content_page.mediabox = mediabox
writer.add_page(content_page)

with open("/home/littlejiver/loadprocesser/Bills/Bison/INV-5163148A.PDF", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

however, I am trying to write it to a specific location with coordinates

How would I do this?

Comment: What do you refer to by coordinates?

Comment: I was think like a canvas with reportlabs or something like that

Comment: The way pdfs are watermarked is basically merging two pages together and keeping the mediabox intact of the original page. You can adjust the watermark page, placing the watermark to the left for example.

Comment: OK that gives me an idea and could work well

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `PyPDF2.pdf.RectangleObject` class to specify the position and size of the stamp on the PDF page. The `RectangleObject` class takes four arguments: lower left x, lower left y, upper right x, and upper right y. These values represent the lower left and upper right corners of a rectangle, in the unit of points. 1 point is equal to 1/72 inch.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```py
import PyPDF2 as pypdf

reader = pypdf.PdfReader("/home/littlejiver/loadprocesser/images/PPB - DIFRTACC.pdf")
image_page = reader.pages[0]

writer = pypdf.PdfWriter()

reader = pypdf.PdfReader("/home/littlejiver/loadprocesser/Bills/Bison/INV-5163148A.PDF")
content_page = reader.pages[0]
mediabox = content_page.mediabox

# Specify the position and size of the stamp
left = 100  # x coordinate of the lower left corner in points
bottom = 100  # y coordinate of the lower left corner in points
right = 200  # x coordinate of the upper right corner in points
top = 200  # y coordinate of the upper right corner in points
rect = pypdf.pdf.RectangleObject([left, bottom, right, top])
image_page.artBox = rect

content_page.merge_page(image_page)
content_page.mediabox = mediabox
writer.add_page(content_page)

with open("/home/littlejiver/loadprocesser/Bills/Bison/INV-5163148A.PDF", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```