# How to specify exact location of stamp when merging PDFs? (PyPDF2)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, pypdf

I have been working on adding a stamp to a PDF file using PyPDF2 and have been successful in adding the stamp, but I am unable to specify the exact location of where the stamp should be placed when the PDFs are merged. I am using the following code and have been playing around and researching for hours with no luck. I am not seeing any affect when I change the values of the RectangleObject for the stamp itself. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I have been viewing the documentation on the PyPDF2 read me pages and even when I change the properties of the RectangleObject, nothing is changing when the PDFs are merged.

https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/user/add-watermark.html#stamp-overlay
https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/modules/RectangleObject.html#PyPDF2.generic.RectangleObject
https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/_modules/PyPDF2/generic/_rectangle.html#RectangleObject.setLowerLeft

There is a similar post back from February, but even when I modify the code I am seeing no differences in the location of my merged PDF stamp.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75341721/how-to-add-a-stamp-to-a-pdf-with-python-pypdf#:~:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20PyPDF2,x%2C%20and%20upper%20right%20y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75341721/how-to-add-a-stamp-to-a-pdf-with-python-pypdf#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20PyPDF2,x%2C%20and%20upper%20right%20y).

Here is the code I am currently using to insert the stamp, I have been playing around with properties for several hours now with no changes to the outcome.

```
def stamp(
    content_pdf: Path,
    stamp_pdf: Path,
    pdf_result: Path,
):
    reader = PdfReader(stamp_pdf)
    image_page = reader.pages[0]

    writer = PdfWriter()

    reader = PdfReader(content_pdf)
    content_page = reader.pages[0]
    mediabox = content_page.mediabox

    # Specify the position and size of the stamp
    left = 100  # x coordinate of the lower left corner in points
    bottom = 100  # y coordinate of the lower left corner in points
    right = 300  # x coordinate of the upper right corner in points
    top = 300  # y coordinate of the upper right corner in points
    rect = PyPDF2.generic.RectangleObject((left, bottom , right, top))
    image_page.mediabox = rect

    content_page.merge_page(image_page)
    content_page.mediabox = mediabox
    writer.add_page(content_page)

    with open(pdf_result, "wb") as fp:
        writer.write(fp)

stamp(content_pdf=pdfFile,
      stamp_pdf=r'test.pdf',
      pdf_result=r'stamped.pdf')
```

I have tried specifying different x/y coordinates, I have read the documentation and set different values for the properties of the RectangleObject, I have tried changing the properties of the media box of the stamp pdf itself with no avail.